# Why parent of fragment is null after pause?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, dependency-injection, android-lifecycle

When I run app and use it no crash. `BottomSheetBehavior` works correctly. But if I return to app after a long time pause in background, it crashing with null point exception when try to cast `view.parent as View` in order to find View with `BottomSheetBehavior`.

Why fragment don't have parent after pause? How to fix it?

I tried to do `binding.root.parent as View` and other `requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_sheet_container)`. But the crash with same case continuous.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ToolboxSheetFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_toolbox_sheet) {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentToolboxSheetBinding
    private lateinit var behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<View>

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding = FragmentToolboxSheetBinding.bind(view)
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(
            view.parent as View // null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.View
        )
    }
```

The parent of fragment is main activity with the next layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    // ...

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_sheet_container"
        android:name=".view.fragment.ToolboxSheetFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="?actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_toolbox_sheet" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{
.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.View
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2792)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.View
        at .view.fragment.ToolboxSheetFragment.onViewCreated(ToolboxSheetFragment.kt:46)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1424)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2968)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2886)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:351)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1335)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7043)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2755)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: the activity gets destroyed to free memeory, try adding  a constructor to your fragment, also try to use setRetainInstance(true);

Comment: did you try using null check `view?.parent as View` ?

Comment: can you show the code how you are opening fragment from activity?

Comment: @WSAyan I didn't write any code in order to open fragment. It opening automatical by `name` tag in `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` in layout. Problem is parent of type ViewParent cant cast to View after pause. As well didn't work `findViewById`

Comment: now I am little bit confused. Why using BottomSheetBehavior inside fragment. Isn't it supposed to be instantiated by id in Activity Class?

Comment: @WSAyan well.. I want to control state of behavior. For example, when click on recycle view, set collapsed state. If I move behavior inside activity have to compose a way to send event from fragment to activity. Because they haven't common ViewModel. Thus one cast inside fragment vs many additional code.

Comment: Please show how and where u use ToolboxSheetFragment

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if I could get full project. But I am suggesting couple of ways here:

**Way 1:**

How about keeping `behavior` inside activity class. instantiate it `onCreate()`. And use it from `ToolboxSheetFragment` like this.

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {
    var behavior: BottomSheetBehavior? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(R.id.sheet_id)
    }
}
```

Then from `ToolboxSheetFragment`

```
class ToolboxSheetFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_toolbox_sheet) {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentToolboxSheetBinding
    var behavior: BottomSheetBehavior? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding = FragmentToolboxSheetBinding.bind(view)
        behavior = (requireActivity() as MainActivity).behavior
    }
```

**Way 2:**

Using `addOnAttachStateChangeListener` on `ToolboxSheetFragment`:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ToolboxSheetFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_toolbox_sheet) {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentToolboxSheetBinding
    private lateinit var behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<View>

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
            override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View?) {
                if(v!=null){
                    binding = FragmentToolboxSheetBinding.bind(v)
                    behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(
                        v.parent as View 
                    )
                }
            }

            override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View?) {
                view.removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this)
            }

        })
    }
```

Comment: Seems like second way is works. But what happening in my case? With clean start cast as View works and after pause crashing. What difference between first creation activity with fragment and re-creation then?

Comment: seems like `onViewCreated` does not ensure view hierarchy is attached when state changes. From the java doc of onViewCreated it is stated:
"this gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves once they know their view hierarchy has been completely created.  The fragment's view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent at this point."

Answer (score 1):

First inflate the layout in `onCreateView()` and you can do all your view related work in `onViewCreated()`.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentToolboxSheetBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help with this problem at all - how the view itself is inflated makes no difference. The root of the issue is the `view.parent as View` call, which your code doesn't do - calling `BottomSheetBehavior.from(view)` doesn't do the same thing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do not ignore `savedInstanceState` and make sure that the `Fragment` is even attached to any `Context`. Sorry for not providing a fully featured answer; just stating the relevant conditions, which the other answers also did not consider. eg. `onAttached()` one can be certain that the `Fragment` is attached - and `savedInstanceState` may or may not be `null`. And when `view.parent` is null, the `View` might not be there. It's possibly the `behavior` of the `MainActivity` and not the `ToolboxSheetFragment`, which is not the same thing.